# MySQL: Looking up list of id's for many to many relationship

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

I have three tables: `keywords`, `queries`, and `keywords_queries`. `keywords_queries` has two columns; one linking to a keywords id and the other linking to a queries id. If I have the id of the query and a list of keywords that I want to link it to, what is the most efficient way to look up the id's of the keywords I have and insert them into the `keywords_queries` table? Obviously I could do a big SELECT query and use the results to build an INSERT query but is there some way to do it in one query? Also the keywords I'm looking up are guaranteed to be in the keywords table.

Comment: Are you trying to create the relationship? Do you have a set of `queryID` and a set of `keywordID` and you want to insert *all combinatation*? Or do you have one `queryID` that you want to connect to multiple `keywordID`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO keywords_queries
    SELECT query.id, keyword.id
      FROM keywords, queries
     WHERE keywords.id in (???)
       AND queries.id = ?
```

Comment: +1 The cross join approach is only viable if he wanted to insert all combinations of all keywords/queries

Comment: Yes, but I preferred to write it this way to in case there is more than 1 query.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested:

```
INSERT INTO keywords_queries (keywordid, queryid) VALUES (
    SELECT myQueryid, keywords.primaryid
    FROM keywords
    WHERE keywords.description IN ('a key','another key','and so on')
  )
```

Comment: Right... that's what inferred from the question. `"If I have the id of the query and ... `